# Control of systems modelled by PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, control-theory

I come from an aerospace engineering background. Currently, doing PhD in the same field, specialization in Control and Dynamical systems.

I am looking for recommendations on how to study PDEs rigorously for the eventual purpose of studying control theory of systems modelled by PDEs.

I started at Lawrence C. Evans's PDE book. However , I couldn't find a good recommendation for a book on the theory of control of PDEs. Probably because of the relatively recent nature of the topic.

I studied a course on PDEs in my undergrad along with a finite element course. I'm particularly interested in air flow control problems.

So in summary, if you can provide recommendations on where to start studying having that eventual purpose in mind, please comment below.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

the following books:

- https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642650260
- [https://www.amazon.com/Boundary-Control-Pdes-Backstepping-Advances/dp/0898716500](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898716500)

the following course where you can find references and lecture notes (might not be in english)
http://www.control.tf.uni-kiel.de/en/teaching/courses/control-of-pde-systems-tu-vienna

the following article from scholarpedia http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Control_of_partial_differential_equations